# Is there a way to dynamically set Object in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a better approach then simple if/else states to render out part of my app that requires conditional logic.

For example, if I have a `<select>` element that uses on an `onChange` to capture an event value like this:

```
<select onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}>
```

I know have my `value` set from my select using:

```
const [ value, setValue ] = useState(null);
```

Is there a way I can create logic that would set that `value` as part of my Object like this:

```
{
    data.<value>.map((item, index) => {
         return (
              <option key={ index }
                      value={ item.displayName }
              >
              { item.displayName }
              </option>
        );
    })
}
```

My `data` object has a bunch of various properties I want to use based on the `value` selected, and I didn't want to create a bunch of if/else or switch statements to try and render.

Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are trying to dynamically access the properties in your "data" object. You can use the bracket notation to achieve that:

```
data[value].map((item, index) => {
     return (
          <option key={ index }
                  value={ item.displayName }
          >
          { item.displayName }
          </option>
    );
})
```

So now you don't need to know what is the name of the property to access. It will be dynamically accessed based on the value of your "value" state variable.